# Can you use "perhaps" at the beginning of a sentence and omit the verb?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence-starts, is-it-a-sentence

For example:

1. More students are emerging with A grades in A level exams. Perhaps as a result of sheer hard work and competition.
2. More students are emerging with A grades in A level exams. **This is** perhaps as a result of sheer hard work and competition.

Is number one a normal usage in English, and is it preferred to number two? The reason for asking is because this sounds very odd to me and it’s not something I've come across often.

For example, I have come across the use of *perhaps* more often in the middle of sentences rather than at the beginning. Hence the reason for this question: are there any rules regarding the use of *perhaps* at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: Please specify your reason for thinking it is not normal. (If you do not have a reason, then you don't have a question.)

Comment: I've edited my question-mind you, this is my first question on this site.

Comment: You didn't just omit the verb, you omitted the subject _and_ the verb. You could say, "Perhaps this is a result of...," but you really need "this is" in there.

Comment: It's a sentence fragment, with conversational deletion. In the UK, GCSE grades are down this year. Perhaps as a result of unwise style choices in writing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for pointing that out, quite useful to know.

Comment: Perhaps.  Perhaps not.  Hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably write the sentence as either 3 or 4:

3. More students are emerging with A grades in A level exams - perhaps as a result of sheer hard work and competition. 
   or
4. More students are emerging with A grades in A level exams as a result of, perhaps, sheer hard work and competition.

Comment: I like your #3.